# 3rd Party: Bandwidth Fluctuation for Asterisk Server

Tags: asterisk, bandwidth-throttling

**Hi!** I'm currently doing a simple 3rd party system on [Asterisk Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_(PBX)), In my system I've already done with measuring bandwidth usage for each call and determined what type of [Codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) being used.My problem is on how to fluctuate the bandwidth on Asterisk server for each call..i really appreciate all of your answer..thank you.

Comment: You mean throttle / restrict the bandwith? You've tagged this question with lots of languages - which one are you actually using?

Comment: Based on a similar/recent question, I suspect whatever language works is fine.

Comment: If you are using TCP, you could use a custom proxy server to control bandwidth and delays.  It not ideal, (not as good as a hardware simulator) but it can be simple to implement.

Comment: @Rup Hi Sir! some kinda, for example if many are using the internet (such streaming, downloading and etc.) then if there is a call i would like to prioritize it to increased the bandwidth when its not enough by lessen the bandwidth to other application..the PL I am using is vb.net but its fine to use c#/c++

Comment: @Peter  Hi Sir!what do you mean sir??? I'am using Asterisk server for voip sir.

Comment: @hearty, what part don't you understand? do you know what a proxy server is/does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically change the amount of network bandwidth with a [traffic shaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping). Since you're already using Linux you may want to try [shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/traffic_shaping.htm) or check Google for GUI tools that use the traffic shaping built into the kernel.